# Azure Search not returning direct matches first

Tags: azure, search, indexing

I have an Azure Search index set up where the name is weighted higher than any other field. The weighting is not weighting direct matches above others. For example if I search "Darkness to Light" the search results are returned in the below order..

Darkness to Light - Test Chapter

Darkness to Light - Chapter two

Darkness to Light

I'm aware of setting weighting for fields but I'm not sure how to even go about fixing this issue. Any ideas would be great